# So what is special about Powershell PSC1 files?

Tags: powershell, powercli

On my PowerShell shortcut I have the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -psc "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\vim.psc1" -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1\""
```

Yet, I would prefer to add the registration of snapins and to run the init of the PowerCLI environment to my profile.

So in my profile I add the following:

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1"
```

Yet, the Get-VICommand is no longer available using this method. Why?

Answer (score 5):

PSC1 files are "PowerShell Console files." They are [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) configuration files that tell PowerShell which snapins to load automatically. The other way to do that would be to call `Import-Module` or `Add-PSSnapin` in your `Profile.ps1` script.

You can create your own psc1 files using `Export-Console`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Scripts\Initialize-PowerCLIEnvironment.ps1' # dot sourcing!
```

Comment: ^ This works, but it really slows down the time it takes for powershell to initialize. Especially if you are running Powershell 3.0 Personally I have the default powershell console parameters on powershell, power-cli and the regular command prompt, each with a different background color to avoid confusion.