# Default Powershell Console Shortcut meaning

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 installed. It has created a windows menu item called "PowerShell Console", at the location

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools

This shortcut contains the following target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\tfshell.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\TFSS
```

In plain text:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\tfshell.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\TFSS

I don't understand three things about it.

a) It opens in the black command window, rather than the new blue powershell screen. However, if I delete everything before the -command.., then it opens in the blue screen. Why is that?

b) I understand that -command means to execute a command after launching powershell. But what follows it, ". C:.... and a path, I can't make any sense of it.

c) I don't even have the folder TFSS in the path which it is giving it.

Is this owing to a faulty installation? I didn't get any errors while installing.

Comment: `TFSS` is a script presumably? `.` is telling powershell to run (dot-source) that script. I assume that skips the normal powershell session initialization (which is what sets up the blue coloring).

Comment: "I don't have the folder TFSS" - are you sure? It's not just hidden?

Comment: When I copy it I also get a black window. Could be v1.0. `-command ". 'path'"` works fine if it is not a folder, i.e. `path` is a path to an executable file. So, once again, are you sure that the file tfss isn't just hidden? running the command for a path that does not exist results in an error message

Answer (score 1):

a) `-PSConsoleFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\tfshell.psc1"` loads a different console file.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502019/so-what-is-special-about-powershell-psc1-files) :

> PSC1 files are "PowerShell Console files." They are XML configuration
>   files that tell PowerShell which snapins to load automatically. The
>   other way to do that would be to call Import-Module or Add-PSSnapin in
>   your Profile.ps1 script.

b/c) As pointed out by @Default, the command `. $path` is only valid for a powershell file (it works with executables but it would run it), and is used to "dot-source it".

(to be complete, it needs : `the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program` as the error message tells us when running it with a folder path)

From [SS64](http://ss64.com/ps/source.html) :

> When a script is Dot-Sourced in the current scope, any functions,
>   aliases, and variables that the script creates become available in the
>   current scope.

This command should allow you to preload useful functions from a powershell file ...

... thus it seems broken. Can you please show us what Get-Item `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\TFSS` outputs on your computer ?

Finally, I truly believe this shortcut target has been cut : you miss at least one single quote (to close the path string) and one double-quote (to close the command string) to make it valid. So would you please mind double checking the target of the shortcut ?

Last but not least, click on the shortcut and tell us what you see : ).

PS : if you only need to strt a PS console, just type `powershell` in your start menu or cmd but I bet you knew that already ^_^